# Dynamic Grid View as Array

Tags: android, gridview

Hey guys I am building an app to show data as grid View and Grid View may be multiple its depend on  Web Service data so I am using Dynamic Grid View objects As array but When I am initializing Grid View objects.. it is showing me  compile time error(NULL Pointer Exception) any one have answer for this question.

```
public class FoodLevelPageOne extends Activity {
private Button home;
private Button back;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private HttpResponse httpResponse;
.....
...
private ArrayList<JsonData> al1[];
private GridView gv[];
....
....
....
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
    ...
    ...
    gv[i] = new GridView(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

**`You have not initialized and specified the size of the array.`**

You should follow these steps:

1. Get the size of the response of the webservice data, i.e. How many gridviews to be shown/filled.

   ```
   JSONArray arrayFromWebservice = new JSONArray(webServiceResponse);
   int SIZE_OF_GRID = arrayFromWebservice.length;
   ```
2. Now, initialize the grid array with the SIZE_OF_GRID variable.

   ```
   gv = new GridView[SIZE_OF_GRID];
   // do some work with the array.
   ```

Comment: Thanks for Helping me actually i was forgot to initialize GridView view like gv=new GridView[size]

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think that you should miss to initialize array of grid view..

```
private GridView gv[] = new GridView[CONTSTANT_NUMBER];
```

or:

You must be use collection framework `Arraylist<GridView>` object to generate dynamic list.